# How to set different values for SMPTE TC and MXF TC in the same file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture, timecodes

As you can see in the attached picture, there are two different timecodes in my file, according to MediaInfo. Is there a way to set them to different values?

Thank you.

[image: MediaInfo information]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-timecode` option with ffmpeg.

I have a similar file and I was able to alter the SMPTE TC and the MXF TC with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mxf -c copy -map 0 -timecode 11:34:56:01 output.mxf
```

Comment: The OP wants to set different values for SMPTE and MXF timecodes.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm not certain if that's what OP wanted. I would be curious to know how different starting timecode values per format would be beneficial to anyone?

Comment: The main question was how to set different values for SMPTE and MXF timecodes if it's possible if for some reasons it wouldn't  possible, please explain why it is so.